# Move player use Input.getKeyDown unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, 2d, transform

Hello guys i want move player between two position use Input.getKeyDown

`firstPosition = new vector2(0,0); secondPosition = new vector2(0,5);`

if player in **firstPosition** will go to **secondPosition** if player press **E** key

if player in **secondPosition** will go to **firstPosition** if player press **E** key

**(movement method is transform.Translate)**

my code

```
if (stairsOn)
    {
        inHelecopter.inHelecopter = true;
        rig2d.simulated = !enabled;
        if (transform.localPosition.y > stairS.maxHigh)//down
        {
            dirUp = false;
        }
        else if (transform.localPosition.y <= stairS.minHigh)
        {//up
            dirUp = true;
        }
        if (transform.localPosition.y >= stairS.maxHigh || transform.localPosition.y <= stairS.minHigh)
        {
            rig2d.simulated = enabled;
            stairsOn = false;
        }
        if (dirUp)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 2 * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.Self);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.down * 2 * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.Self);

        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: yes i do i edit my qusetion

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool b = true;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        if (b)
        {
            transform.Translate(secondPosition - firstPosition);
            b = false;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(firstPosition - secondPosition);
            b = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In practice, I assign a variable that controls whether it is in the first or second position and moves the player towards the other.
In this script I use the transform.Translate method, but if you can I recommend that you simply assign the position like this:
bool b = true;

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        if (b)
        {
            transform.position = secondPosition;
            b = false;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = firstPosition;
            b = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Good work!

Comment: can u see my code in question i add it